# List of Python Object Databases

Tags: python, database, nosql, object-oriented-database

I am looking for an object database for Python (no handmade pickles :D).

What are my options (besides the obvious [ZODB](http://www.zope.org/Documentation/Articles/ZODB1))?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MongoDB perhaps comes close - not object oriented but document-oriented and coming close to object databases.

Comment: MongoDB is not an Object database, it's a Document Database. It doesn't store Python Objects.

Answer (score 7):

[Dobbin](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/dobbin). Somewhat similar to ZODB, but much simpler. It looks nice but I haven't tried it myself. I haven't been able to find much information about it. It has been at version 0.2 for over a year. I don't know if it is still being actively maintained, if it is reliable enough for mission-critical applications.

From the description on the site, the main difference between Dobbin and other object databases is that persisted objects are read-only unless they are explicitly "checked out". This may make dealing with objects a little trickier, but it may make the database faster and more memory-efficient.

Answer (score 5):

- handmade [shelves](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html)? ;-)
- [Durus](http://www.mems-exchange.org/software/durus/)?
- [SqlAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/)? it's not an object database, but chances are that you could use it

Check [PersistenceTools](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PersistenceTools) on the python.org wiki, which mentions a few that might count. (the [DatabaseProgramming](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DatabaseProgramming/) page also mentions [Matisse](http://www.matisse.com/product_information/language_bindings/lang_python.html) under "Non-relational Databases", I don't know it, just mention it because for some reason, it's not included on that other page)

Answer (score 3):

[DyBASE](http://www.garret.ru/dybase.html) by [Konstantin Knizhnik](http://www.garret.ru) who developed a lot of embedded databases for multiple programming languages. It has transactions and indices. There are tests in the distribution and I use it myself for persisting elements in a Python Queue. My example is also available at github as [python-persistence-queue](https://github.com/srw/python-persistent-queue)

Answer (score 0):

Cog:

Seems not updating for a long time.

[itamarst.org/software/cog](http://itamarst.org/software/cog)

And this is a paper on 6th International Python conf. about object database.
https://legacy.python.org/workshops/1997-10/proceedings/shprentz.html