# Recommended NoSQL Database for use with Python

Tags: python, database, nosql

What are the **popular NoSQL databases** that are used with Python ? I know there are a few options as explained at http://nosql-database.org/ but which one does python programmers use/recommend the most?

Comment: NoSQL covers a variety of database types (key-value stores, document stores, graph databases) each with its own use case. The question shouldn't be which is the most common/popular but which one fits your usage needs.

Comment: yeah - you are right but i'm asking what are the most popular nosql db for pythonistas

Answer (score 24):

Most of the nosql databases have python clients which are actively supported.  Pick your database based on your usage needs.  Using it from python shouldn't be a problem.
To name a few:
Cassandra: https://github.com/datastax/python-driver
Riak: https://github.com/basho/riak-python-client
MongoDB: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/
CouchDB: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Getting_started_with_Python
Redis: https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py

Answer (score 15):

I like mongodb.  Basically you can just throw a dictionary into a database, which makes it very easy to use from python.  I haven't seen a consensus on one specific nosql database.  I would suggest trying a couple of them.  Redis is pretty neat and couchdb is in the mix.

http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html

Answer (score 5):

Be sure to take a look at [ZODB](http://www.zodb.org/en/latest/). It's an exceedingly easy-to-use, Python-based database that covers a large range of use cases and has been used in production environments for many years.

Comment: That link is broken.  A more current link is http://www.zodb.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the standard NOSQL databases mentioned by Zanzon you might also try:

- [shelve](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html?highlight=shelve#shelve), which is a document database provided as part of the python standard library, and uses [anydbm](http://docs.python.org/2/library/anydbm.html) as a backend. it supports anything that can be pickled.
- [shove](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/shove/0.5.6), which is similar to [shelve](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html?highlight=shelve#shelve) but with a wide choice of backends including dbm, ZODB, Redis, Mongo et al.
- [ZODB](http://www.zodb.org/en/latest/), which is part of the Zope framework - I'd recommend using this on its own only if you also use Zope.

I myself have recently started using shelve with a decent amount of success - the only caution I'd give you is that it does not play well with the default OSX version of python - in fact issues with low file size limits (hundreds of KiB) have been noted on 2.7.1<=python<=2.7.3 . I however have no issued on the brew version of python 2.7.5

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend [DyBASE](http://www.garret.ru/dybase.html). It is not popular but it is an excellent Python object database before the NoSQL term existed. I answered a similar question at [List of Python Object Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106212/list-of-python-object-databases).